# Why is my EL-100 not firing on my T7/2000D with a sync contact on the hotshoe?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, hotshoe-flash

I’m having a similar issue, I bought the EOS 2000d from Canon recently with an EL-100 speedlite. I can not get the speedlite to flash. My camera does have the sync connector on the hotshoe.

Comment: a similar issue to who/what?

Comment: Check this manual and confirm your camera manage the flash: https://www.eos-magazine.com/articles/flash/canon-speedlite-el-100-review.html

Answer (score 1):

Your camera and flash are both compatible with each other. When you say “sync connector”, I assume you mean the center pin on the camera hotshoe.

With the flash installed on the camera, go into the External Speedlite flash menu, and insure that flash firing is enabled.

Try using the flash both using the optical viewfinder, and LiveView, as there are some differences in flash firing in LiveView.

If flash firing is enabled, but you still can’t get the flash to fire, you may need to get the camera and/or flash serviced under warranty by Canon.

[image]

Comment: The EOS 2000D is one of the "nobbled" cameras without a centre pin (angry face) https://www.p4pictures.com/2019/03/how-to-trigger-studio-strobes-with-eos-2000d-4000d/

Comment: Canon has once again started to include the center pin on the latest 2000D cameras. In any case, the center pin is not needed when using compatible Canon brand Speedlites.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, a lot of more recent T7/2000D owners are [reporting the center contact has been reinstated on their copies](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskPhotography/comments/klroo5/why_does_my_eos_2000d_have_a_hot_shoe_center_pin/).

Comment: Today I learned, thanks folks.